# Deleting file at end of Chef run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I want to delete file at the end of Chef run.
I am using the following `file resource` to achieve that

```
file "#{home_dir['data']}/file1.txt" do
  action :delete
  retries 3
  retry_delay 50
  only_if { ::File.exist? "#{home_dir['data']}/file1.txt" }
end
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: It's not really (certainly) _at the end_, but during the chef run.

Comment: @mealhour you dont to use the if and only_if .. its already idempotent. And to ur question It's done during the chef run

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, but you don't need the `only_if`, the file resource is internally idempotent already. You also probably don't need the `retries` unless you actually expect `unlink()` to fail (like if this is a weird network file system), but it doesn't hurt anything.

EDIT: How to avoid resource cloning if you have the same resource type+name in your recipes twice.

```
file "delete #{home_dir['data']}/file1.txt (or some other unique name)" do
  path "#{home_dir['data']}/file1.txt"
  action :delete
end
```

The `path` property defaults to use the name if not specified, but they can be changed independently to avoid collisions.

Comment: it is not working. i have other portions of the recipe that is creating `"/path/to/file.txt"`  Now in the end i want to delete the file. `file "#{home_dir['data']}/file1.txt" do
  action :delete
  retry_delay 50
end` This is not workiing

Comment: even though i am putting `file resource` in the end, it seems it runs before other commands

Comment: If you have the same resource type+name pair twice in your recipe code, you might be hitting resource cloning issues. You should see a warning printed. I've added how to avoid them to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working but i see a random behaviour. Sometimes, the file gets and deleted and sometimes it is not. Please suggest what could be the reason for this random behaviour??

Comment: There is no randomness. Look through your logs and check what state things are in at each point.